# Finding E(X) when X ~ Exp(θ) and Var(X) when X ~ Exp(λ)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Below are the questions and my answers. For Q2, I get E(X) = θ rather than E(X) = 1/θ - I am unsure where I have gone wrong as have done it multiple times but keep getting E(X) = θ. I then used the correct answer (as given in Q2 of E(X) = 1/θ) to answer Q4. Where may I have gone wrong in Q2, and as a result in Q4?

[image: Q2]

[image: Q4]

[image: Q2 my answer]

[image: Q2 answer continued]

[image: Q4 my answer]
[image: Q4 answer continued]

Comment: It is the policy of this site to discourage users from using pictures for main portions of their post. You can use them to add further context to your problem but the main body of your question must be formatted in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). This post is therefore likely to attract downvotes and closure.

Comment: Makes sense will attempt to format now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot read your work very well, but:

First, your pdf is very incorrect. If a random variable $Y \thicksim \exp(\theta)$,  then $$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} \theta e ^{- \theta y} & \text{ if $y \geq 0$} \\ 0 &\text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$
Next, you may find it easier to substitute $u = - \theta x$ in the first step, since you have less floating around constant's to deal with.

On the second question: if you fix these mistakes you will have the correct answer. Good try and good luck!

To check your answers since they are easily googleable, if $X \thicksim \exp(\theta)$:
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{1}{\theta}\\ \operatorname{Var}(X) = \frac{1}{\theta^2}$$

Comment: @Davide Giraudo Thank you for the edit I never knew `\operatorname` what a thing.